# activiti 6.0.0.0 with SpringBoot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, alfresco, activiti

I have a SpringBoot project with activity 6, but when deploying I have this error:

```
Caused by: org.activiti.engine.ActivitiException: couldn't upgrade db schema: alter table ACT_RE_PROCDEF add (ENGINE_VERSION_ NVARCHAR2(255))
```

Comment: What Database are you connecting to? Is it an empty database or are you re-using one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check wich version of activiti engine  you use in maven dependencies.

Check version in your db table ACT_GE_PROPERTY and org.activiti.engine.ProcessEngine.VERSION. They need match.